# Part of foreach in tpl.php of the View acts strange [Drupal]

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I created foreach in tpl.php of the View and it looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php foreach($view->result as $result): ?>
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="<?php print file_create_url($result->field_field_client_image[0]['raw']['uri']); ?>" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

My View has only one image field. Now I have two nodes and each of them have only one image, as output I should get:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
       <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item active">
       <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

but I got:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

which is very strange.

My content type that I'm showing through Views has only one field for image and it is limited on 1 image file only.

Does someone have any idea what is the possible problem?

Comment: That's really very strange, because you don't have inner foreach inside your template. Why does it print so many inner divs? Try to `var_dump($result)` inside your foreach to see, how it executes.

Comment: @user4035 I already try that, I'm also using Devel module so I looked through everything with `dpm($result)`, everything looks good, nothing strange...

Comment: I don't think, we'll be able to help you without debugging on your side. Try to remove all php inside `foreach` and keep only static text inside. How does it behave?

Comment: I tried that also, it acts the same as before, when I use `dpm($result)` there is two items (objects) so I'm very confused...

Comment: The problem was in plugin that adds this additional divs, there is no problem in php...